# C++ Standalone application

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-2010

please someone tell me how to make standalone applications in C++ Builder, without runtime files ?
I know that I must check and uncheck something in the menu, but can you tell me what exactly are they? Please make a note that I am using C++ Builder 2010

Comment: On which operating system, and what for?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and need that i could use my exe file on any windows platform without runtime libraries

Comment: My question is clear, your answer is not the answer to my question, please don't waste my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I don't have the application in front of me and can't 100% guarantee this answer, but maybe I can help. 
If I'm slightly off I'll correct this answer later.

---

*Off the top of my head:*

In the Project Settings menu, go into **C++ Linker** section, and set **"Dynamic RTL"** to false.

Then in the **Packages** section of the Project Settings menu, uncheck **"Build with Runtime Packages"**.